# I am trying to do a JavaScript string that ensures data input into the examnumber field is exactly 4 digits, can someody lend a hand?

Tags: javascript, html

This is what i have so far, i am wanting to set so that text input into the Exam Number field is exactly 4 digits. i am having trouble because whatever I try does not work, if anyone could lend a hand and maybe even post full code after that would be great

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org        /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Exam Entry</title>

    <script language="javascript"" type="text/javascript">

    function validateForm() {
            var result = true;
            var msg="";

    if (document.ExamEntry.name.value=="") {
            msg+="You must enter your name \n";
            document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
            document.getElementById('name').style.color="red";
            result = false;
    }

    if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value=="") {
            msg+="You must enter the subject \n";
            document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
            document.getElementById('subject').style.color="red";
            result = false;
    }

    if (document.ExamEntry.examnumber.value=="") {
            msg+="You must enter the exam number \n";
            document.ExamEntry.examnumber.focus();
            document.getElementById('examnumber').style.color="red";
            result = false;
    }

    if (document.ExamEntry.examnumber.length==<4) {
            msg+="You must make your exam number exactly 4 digits \n";
            document.ExamEntry.examnumber.focus();
            document.getElementById('examnumber').style.color="red";
            result = false;
    }

    if(msg==""){
    return result;
    }
    {
    alert(msg)
    return result;
            }

    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>
      <form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html">
       <table width="50%" border="0">
            <tr>
                            <td id="name">Name</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                            <td id="subject">Subject</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="subject" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                            <td id="examnumber">Exam Number</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="examnumber" maxlength="4"         size="4"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                            <td><input type="submit" name="Submit"         value="Submit"         onclick="return validateForm();" /></td>
                            <td><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" /></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </body>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: should it be `document.ExamEntry.examnumber.length!==4`?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular expression to make sure the entry consists of exactly four digits and nothing else:

```
if (!document.ExamEntry.examnumber.value.match(/^\d{4}$/)) {
  ...
}
```

^ anchors the matching at the start of the string (meaning nothing can come before what the regex matches), \d is the same as [0-9], i.e. the set of digits, {4} means there has to be exactly four of the previous (digits in this case), and $ anchors the matching at the end of the string (meaning nothing can come after what the regex matches).

String.prototype.match() returns null when there is no match, otherwise an array of matches, which will evaluate to true when used as a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Regular Expression to test for 4 *digits*;

```
if (!/^\d{4}$/.test(document.ExamEntry.examnumber.value)) {
   msg+="You must make your exam number exactly 4 digits \n";
   ...
```

As it stands you would need the line:

```
document.ExamEntry.examnumber.value.length <= 4
```

Comment: Don't you mean `!=` rather than `<=` ?

Comment: Where should i put these??

Comment: Where you currently have `if (document.ExamEntry.examnumber.length==<4) {`. I thought the whole question was about improving that part of the logic?